# Is there a way in SwiftUI to detect if a user has Larger Text size enabled?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've read all the articles about supporting dynamic text size, but my problem is that I have a view consisting of shapes and some text.  I needed to hard code the height of this view, so when a user uses a larger text size the text overlaps the shapes.  What I would like to do is detect when a larger text size is used and increase the hard coded height of the view.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an environment value for that:

```swift
@Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
```

With that, you can do stuff like:

```swift
if sizeCategory > ContentSizeCategory.large {
    // views for large text
} else {
    // views for regular/small text
}
```

You should also check out the `@ScaledMetric` property wrapper, which will auto-scale your var based on the user’s text size:

```swift
@ScaledMetric var height: CGFloat = 100
```

Here's a nice summary of both: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/10/09/dynamic-type-in-swiftui/

Comment: From iOS 16+, use `dynamicTypeSize` instead https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/sizecategory